# How can I access data inside struct?

Tags: c

I am trying to access the account number, name and address and print it in the function void printAllRecords, however after I add a new record using the function addRecord it still does not print the data saved. They are not letting me post my code so I add just the 2 functions. Any help would be amazing. Thanks, guys. Assume I call the functions from the main.

```
 struct record
{
  int accountno;
  char name[25];
  char address[80];
  struct record *next;
};
   

    /*print all the records in the database */
void printAllRecords (struct record *start)
{
  while (start != NULL)
    {

      printf ("%d\n%s\n%s\n", start->accountno, start->name, start->address);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get why start is a double pointer, nor why you are passing in an arg for each member of your struct.  But this will show you how to use scanf with your struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

 struct record
{
  int account;
  char name[25];
  char address[80];
  struct record *next;
};
    
int addRecord (struct record *rec)
{

  printf ("Enter your account number:\n");
  scanf ("%d", &(rec->account));

  while (rec->account < 0)
    {
      printf ("Error: Enter a valid account number.\n");
      scanf ("%d", &(rec->account));
    }

  //emptyStdin (); /*function to clean the buffer*/

  printf ("Enter your name:\n");
  scanf("%s", rec->name);
  //fgets ((rec->name), 25, stdin);

  printf ("Enter your residential address:\n");
  //getaddress (address, 80); /*function to get multiple lines of input from the user*/

  return 1;
}



int main()
{
    struct record rec;
    addRecord(&rec);
    printf("%d %s, %s", rec.account, rec.name, rec.address);
    return 0;
}
```